# How does miro embed vlc

Tags: python, audio, open-source, embed, vlc

I am sorry if this sounds like a dumb question, but I am looking at the code to see how VLC can be embedded in another program.

Some time ago, I read that Miro uses VLC library or source code.
However I cannot find any references to VLC in the Miro source code.

The question is: How does miro embed vlc?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to find out is to look at the Miro source code, which can be browsed on GitHub here: https://github.com/pculture/miro/

BTW, Miro says they use Gstreamer and Xine on Linux, not VLC.  The OSX version uses Quicktime.  Only the Windows version uses VLC, so that suggests focussing on this area of the code:
https://github.com/pculture/miro/tree/master/tv/windows

From there, a grep turns up this:

```
plat/xulhelper.py:pcfIDTVVLCRenderer = components.interfaces.pcfIDTVVLCRenderer
```

Looking a few lines above that, you'll see:

```
from xpcom import components
```

So, VLC is being used somehow via XPCom.  From there, you would have to figure out how XPCOM and VLC are talking together.  If you aren't already tied to XULRunner and XPCOM, I would suggest finding another way to do this.  If you goal to use VLC from inside your own Python program?  Inside your own C/C++ program?  What GUI toolset are you using?

Response to comment:

If you like java, http://caprica.github.io/vlcj/ is vlc java bindings that look ok, but warning I'm not really a Java guy.

For python, you could try pyqt and vlc-qt, but that could take some fiddling.

If you know a little C++, using Qt, and either libVLC directly or vlc-qt would probably be easiest.  If you don't already know C++ and Qt, then it wouldn't be.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply.
I am looking to create a very light weight mp3 player that'd use a lot of VLC features (mp3 and radio playback, as well as streaming music over network to other machines).
I am choosing between using Java and Python. Both have VLC wrappers, yet very little documentation...
Miro is missing some of the key VLC features that I'd like to extend, radio playback and streaming.
Any advice/suggestion/pointer is greatly appreciated since I am a very junior developer atm :)